invalid src props in nextjs iamge
I am trying to fetch udemy courses from backend but i keep getting this error when i use Image component.
Error: Invalid src prop (https://img-b.udemycdn.com/course/750x422/1943926_e313.jpg) on next/image, hostname "img-b.udemycdn.com" is not configured under images in your next.config.js
this is the next.config.js
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  optimizeFonts: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'img-b.udemycdn.com',
        pathname: '**',
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;


Leave pathname blank and instead add an empty string as a port property as:
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  optimizeFonts: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'img-b.udemycdn.com',
        port: '',
      },
    ],
  },
};


